# Mysterious Icon appearing in my taskbar

Tags: windows-10, icons

I'm using Windows 10 home for a long time but recently there is an icon appearing in the notification area near the time & date indicator in the lower right hand corner of my laptop screen. It seems to appear randomly, while i'm using other normal daily applications, and when I saw it appear,  I try to right-click / left-click it with my mouse, but then it disappears again.

I was wondering if anyone could help identify what it is? what is it doing? and how can I stop it? (see below)

[image: attached picture]

The mysterious icon is circled in red and I edited the picture a bit to give it more brightness because the icon itself is colored very dark (low contrast with the taskbar) yet still noticeable when it appears.

Answer (score 0):

It is taskbar notification area, open:
Action Center – All Settings – System – Notifications & actions – Show notifications from these apps.

By the method of exclusion, only enable one app notification at a time, using the system and wait for a period of time. Then, we can identify which app is relate to this icon.

Besides, we can check Task Manager – Process tab, confirm that if we can find it within these running process.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang